# Are real-valued functions of real variables also complex functions?

Tags: calculus, definition

The definition my lecturer gave for a complex function was that it is one whose domain and/or range is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ that is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

But according to [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zWErAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&dq=real%20valued%20function%20of%20a%20real%20variable%20complex%20function&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij7taymePTAhVgF8AKHcERBmYQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q&f=false) book, any real-valued function of a real variable is a complex function. This seems a little strange to me, because if that were the case then wouldn't it suggest all results in complex analysis also hold in real analysis (which of course they don't)?

Comment: In short, the definition doesn't matter much because the hypotheses of most of those complex analysis theorems would include things like "the function's domain contains a disk" which would rule out functions whose domain is just the reals.

Comment: @MarkS. Aha that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Any real function can be extended in an arbitrary manner to a function on the complex numbers, but even if has real derivatives of every order, it may not be possible to extend it to a function with a complex derivative.